# Is there enough of a difference between WebSphere 8.5.5 on Linux vs Windows to warrant testing our application in WebSphere on both operating systems?

Tags: websphere

We have customers who deploy our application in WebSphere. Some use Linux others Windows. To minimize testing efforts we were looking to validate the possibility of just testing on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the risk is fairly low - the "write once, run anywhere" promise of Java holds up pretty well when you keep the app server and underlying JVM constant. Here are the general areas where (in my experience, at least) you'll need to be careful across the two platforms:

- Batch/shell scripts - Not something you'd need to worry about in pure Java, but in the event you've got anything scripted outside the server process, this is something to be aware of. My guess, though, is that you wouldn't be considering skipping Linux testing if you had shell scripts to worry about.
- Environment variables - Talking just about OS-level environment variables; anything you define within the server config should be safe.
- File/path separators - Hopefully you're careful about using variables rather than hard-coding them so this won't be an issue.
- File sorting - This is a sneaky one. Windows will sort files within a directory in a predictable order. Linux will not - it can depend on the vagaries of file system settings and maybe OS levels and whatnot. In a well-packaged app, this won't matter... but if you have any duplicate classes in WEB-INF/lib or EAR/lib, and they're not absolutely identical, it can break you. Make sure that you're not including multiple versions of any dependencies, because it's possible that the contents of those /lib directories will get pulled into the class path in different orders on different OSes (or even different systems with the same OS).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would add to @Jarid list the fact that, in Windows, file names are not case sensitive and this can cause problem depending of the technologies you are using in your applications (ie JSP file names, properties files etc). In this regards, if it works on Linux, it will work in Windows but the reverse may not be truw

It happend to us...

And also the underlying JDK may have different "behavior" and also differents "bugs" depending on the platform you use